# Action<ISomeInterface> use for configuration

Tags: c#, delegates

Yesterday, I watched a RabbitMQ course on Pluralsight. I noticed that they used Action delegate as a method parameter to set come configurations. So, there were already some settings in the method, and if there is a requirement to add more configuration, we can pass it by the Action delegate parameter. The way, they used Action Delegate as a parameter with an interface, was new for me. So, I try to replicate it in a test console application. Not sure, I implemented it perfectly or not.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // If I want to set/add configuration, I can send it by Action delegate.
        Program.DoSomeConfiguration((cdd) =>
        {
            cdd.SetConfig("New Config");
        });

        // If I do not want to set new configuration and just want to execute it. 
        // Call 'DoSomeConfiguration' with null.

        //Program.DoSomeConfiguration();
    }

    public static void DoSomeConfiguration(Action<ITest> actionMy = null)
    {
        ConfigClass obj = new ConfigClass();
        obj.MyConfigurations.Add("Old Config");
        obj.SetConfig();

        Console.WriteLine("**************************************");

        actionMy?.Invoke(obj);
    }
}

public interface ITest
{
    void SetConfig(string config);
}

public class ConfigClass : ITest
{
    public List<string> MyConfigurations { get; set; }

    public ConfigClass()
    {
        MyConfigurations = new List<string>();
    }
    public void SetConfig(string config = null)
    {
        if (config != null)
        {
            MyConfigurations.Add(config);
        }

        foreach (var configuration in MyConfigurations)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"config {configuration}");
        }
    }
}
```

MyCode explanation: I have some default configuration in the "DoSomeConfiguration" method. If anyone wants to add more configuration to it, they can pass it by Action Delegate.

Did I use it correctly?

Comment: I think this question belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Also: what does "correctly" really mean here? If it works for you, then I guess it's a yes.

Comment: Your code is a bit all over the place. You're doing weird things, like calling `obj.SetConfig();` to get the side-effect of displaying the current configuration rather than actually setting the config as the method name suggests. Also, exposing `public List<string> MyConfigurations { get; set; }` is a bad idea.

Comment: @Xerillio is correct, there are so many ways to do what you want, and many use cases.

Answer (score 1):

It is not seen how you use those configurations. Because ConfigClass obj is not accessible out side DoSomeConfiguration. Regarding ConfigClass - MyConfigurations shouldn't be exposed and SetConfig has more than one resposibility - sent config and print out config values (I assume when null is passed purpose it just to print out config values)